# JFrame Window goes black when I add a paint method

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, awt, graphics2d

so when i try to create a paint method i.e.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
}
```

my JFrame window will go completely black when I run my program. If I remove the paint method from the code, my normal images will appear in my JFrame window. I know FOR SURE that I am not using a .paint() method anywhere else in my code because I just added this method to my code now. Does anybody know why this is happening?

update, I am using eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to be better understand how painting works in Swing.

Basically, the paint subsystem is calling your `paint` method as required, when it decides that the component needs to be updated.

Because you've overridden it to basically do nothing, then nothing is painted.

As a general piece of advice, you should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, because they are actually composite components.  That is, they are actually made of a series of layers which the UI is built on

See [How to use root panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details, but basically...

[image: All the layers]

Comment: Perfectly put :)